# Making POST using Instagram/Maker through IFTTT not requesting API url

Tags: mongodb, instagram, ifttt

I'm using IFTTT with Instagram to get a new photo by anyone with specific hashtag.

This trigger fires every time anyone shares a public photo with a specific hashtag you specify.  I'm using Maker to make the web request.  I add the URL to my API which is capable of handling a POST (when sending through Postman, using the x-www-form-urlencoded a document is created in my MongoDB).  For whatever reason, I'm not getting any documents added to Mongo when going through Maker.  My settings in Maker are:

```
Method = POST

Content Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body = Username={{Username}}&Caption={{Caption}}&CreatedAt={{CreatedAt}}&SourceUrl={{SourceUrl}}&Url={{Url}}&CaptionNoTag={{CaptionNoTag}}
```

I also tried sending the body as a JSON object as well just to see if that would work but I get nothing either way.  I haven't been able to find any actual examples of how to do this, so I was hoping someone has dealt with this before.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours and hours of trial and error, I realized that my problem was the CreatedAt value.  In my Mongoose schema, I had that value expecting a date but in ifttt, it's actually a string.  That for whatever reason prevented all other Instagram parameters from posting.  The only parameters that were posting were none Insta parameters that I added in addition to what I had above.  So rule of thumb, when dealing with ifttt and insta params, everything is a string.  Hopefully this will help someone else shall the problem ever come up again.